# How to do reverse debugging in Xcode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xcode6

In Visual Studio , I can do "Intellitrace" and do reverse debugging. How can I do the same in Xcode. I don't want to restart the app again and again.

Comment: You should add an explanation of what Intellitrace and reverse debugging are along with what you are trying to do. You can't assume iOS and Mac developers are familiar with Visual Studio. I wouldn't assume Windows developers were familiar with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversible debugging is one thing where Linux outshines both Windows and OS-X. Intellitrace gives you something vaguely like reversible debugging, but it's really not the full deal. On Linux you have in-built reversible debugging in gdb, open-source projects such as rr (https://github.com/mozilla/rr) , and commercial things such as my company's UndoDB (http://undo-software.com/). Real reversible debugging means you can step/continue backwards as well as forwards to any point in the program's execution history, and also that you can see all the data at any point in its history. When you have this, watchpoints (aka data breakpoints) in reverse are particularly powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment, but only reply: Here is a blog post that explains what IntelliTrace is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/16/intellitrace-in-visual-studio-ultimate-2015.aspx

Comment: Visual studio undoubtedly is a great debugger tool , with advancements like reverse debugging , cursor flow and debugging threads, without wasting execution flow.